# В зависимости от option поменять логику вычисления в 2х input'ах

Tags: javascript, select, input

Есть select и 2 input number.
Как сделать чтобы, при изменении select менялась логика вычисления в input-ах.
Функция будет одна и таже меняться будет только аргумент, попробовал сделать функцию с помощью  switchcase или это неправильный подход?

```
var changeDependOnOption = function() {
    var game = document.getElementById('sel').value;
        switch (game) {
            case 'choise1': change(3);
                break;
            case 'choise2': change(2);
                break;
            case 'choise3': change(4);
                break;
            case 'choise4': change(5);
                break;                  
        }
function change(argument) {
   var temp = document.getElementById("input1").value;
   document.getElementById("input2").value = temp * argument;  
}

<p> <select id="sel">
                <option value="choise1">choise1</option>
                <option value="choise2">choise2</option> 
                <option value="choise3">choise3</option>
                <option value="choise4">choise4</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="input1" type="number" name="input1" oninput="changeDependOnOption()">
</p>
<p>
    <input id="input2" type="number" name="input2" min="0" placeholder="">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать, например, следующим образом:

```
<script>
    var actualFunc = func0;
    function func0() { /* ... */ }
    function func1() { /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
    function onSeclectChange() {
        switch (document.getElementById("sel").selectedIndex) {
            case 0:
                actualFunc = func0;
                break;
            case 1:
                actualFunc = func1;
                break;
            /* ... */
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- ... ->
<select id="sel" oncange="onSelectChange();">
    <option value="choise1">choise1</option>
    <option value="choise2">choise2</option>
</select>
<input oninput="actualFunc();">
```

Здесь при смене выбранной опции меняется значение переменной, содержащей функцию-обработчик. Такой подход работает быстрее, поскольку не требуется каждый раз при смене значения в `input` искать в DOM требуемый узел, а затем выполнять сравнения в `switch`. Кроме того, он не зависит от каких-либо внешних библиотек.

Comment: Спасибо, работает безупречно.
Обязательно ли в case должны стоять цифры, или можно значения подставить?
А если цифры объясните поэалуйста почему?

Comment: @WiAim Нет, совершенно необязательно цифры. Можно строки, т.е. `option.value`. А цифры взял просто для примера.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так

```
 <script>

    function setCRC(){

    var variant = $('#OutSum  option:selected').val();

    if(variant == 'v1') { умножить } 

    if(variant == 'v2') { сложить } 

    if(variant == 'v3') { делить } 

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

     setCRC();

    });

    </script>

    <select id="OutSum" name="OutSum" onChange="setCRC()">
        <option value="v1">v1</option>
        <option value="v2">v2</option>
        <option value="v3">v3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Собственно вы сделали так как и я бы сделал. Но можно еще например в качестве параметра функции которую вы вызываете changeDependOnOption( document.getElementById('sel').value ) передать что выбрано в select.Такой подход верный и он должен работать. Нету смысла писать какой-либо велосипед и придумывать что-то сверхсложное. Могу вам посоветовать посмотреть в сторону Angularjs там можно это отслеживать при изменении input / select то есть там можно слушателя событий накладывать и уже дальше с этим что-то делать.  Только я не совсем понял что у вас за литерал в switch( server ), что это за переменная?Или что это?откуда она у вас идет?

Comment: Не знаю почему но не работает, server ошибка исправил

Comment: Я могу ошибаться , но в вашем коде проблема может быть в одинарных скобках. Проверти это , попробуйте двойные. А пробовали найти что именно не работает?

Comment: Скобки менял, но не работает все равно, я думаю не может прочитать значение select